# Returning forum data

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

I have a search forum that takes a users input and checks it against a MySQL database. Every thing works great unless I move to the second page of the search results at that point all the forum data erases. I tried to do make it work with  `$PHP_SELF` and `<a>` to no avail. Code below. Thank you in advance.

```
<a href=\"$PHP_SELF?query=$query&page=$second_prev_page&limit=$limit\"> $second_prev </a>
```

Comment: Please give more information, php code, queries, and what do you mean by "all the .. data erases" ?

Comment: did you create `$PHP_SELF` or did you mean `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to explain everything I've gathered together to build the site so far.  I was using //$PHP_SELF//  to return back the same webpage I was currently on. Idea being it would return me to the same page including the parameters entered into the search plus the new page. Right now it returns the same page and forwards to the second results page but doesn't carry over the imputed parameters (acts as if all parameters were left blank) Sorry if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: May be your $query is overwritten by the time you get to this link.